# The <Link> from react-router-dom does not change the URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am currently in process of making a website, and hit a wall on this. I am using react-router-dom for routing my app, and kinda new to it, but in one page, the link that I put on the page does not change the URL

I already tried on previous component, in which I put the button on one component, then use the Link to load another component based on the Link and Route given. However, on this one, despite using similar structure as before, does not work at all

This is the code for the page that loads. I already imported the BrowserRouter as Link from react-router-dom

```
<div>
  <p>TEST</p>
   <Link to="/leadslist"><button class="btn btn-success">Back to Leads List</button></Link>
</div>
```

This is the target page

```
            <div>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Redirect from="/leads" to="/leadslist" />
                    <Route path="/leadsForm" component={LeadsForm} />
                    <Route path="/leadslist" component={LeadsList} />
                    <Route path="/leaddetails" component={LeadsDetails}/>
                 </Switch>
            </Router>
            </div>
```

my previous try clicking button from "/leadslist" to "/leadsForm" actually worked, but then I try to load to "leaddetails" to try to go back to "/leadslist", but it doesn't change the URL at all. Any help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be importing `BrowserRoute` as `Link` from the `react-router-dom`. Both are different things. You need to import `Link` directly from `react-router-dom`. Rest, it should work solid.

You should be importing `link` this way:

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

Now, I am not sure what's exactly happening your app. But [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-leakey-g0f9s?fontsize=14), I have created a very basic demo or working react-router using CodeSandBox. You can take a look, it should help you fix the problem you are having.

Also, you can read this [article](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/understanding-the-fundamentals-of-routing-in-react-b29f806b157e) to further understand the working of the react router.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that immediately works. If I may know, what differs between using the ones with {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link} and the ones directly like {Link} etc.?

Comment: `{BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link}` imports three things, `Router, Route, and Link`. While `{Link}` imports only link. Probably the mistake you were doing was that you were importing `BrowserRouter as Link` which means, `BrowserRouter` named as `Link`. Then you were using `Link` (BrowserRouter) to direct to that route. Instead, you needed an actual `Link` only. You can read further in the article that I have linked in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because you have added button inside Link tag so on click of button React only fires onClick method of button and Link will no be clicked!

So in solution, you can remove a button from Link tag

```
<Link to="/leadslist">Back to Leads List</Link>
```

or You can use Below solution,

Instead of adding button in Link You should do this,

```
import withRouter from 'react-router-dom'   
const Component = (props) => {
    <div>
        <Button onClick={()=>props.history.push('/leadslist')}
    </div>
  }
export default withRouter(Component)
```

Add HOC withRouter to your component and you can get history object in prop.

Comment: This saved a lot of time for me! This should be addressed more clearly in docs, imo